# Android email gets sent on the emulator but not on the device

Tags: android, email, emulation

I wrote an application that sends an email in Android. When I tested it on the emulator, it works just fine but when I test it on a device, it gives me a:

> could not connect to smtp.gmail.com at port 456.

Any ideas how this happens?

Comment: nevermind. the device was using mobile network but it does not have any prepaid credits that's why it cannot connect to the internet

Answer (score 1):

your port number is incorrect, the port number of smtp.gmail.com is 465, not 456